# Can't install numpy

Tags: windows, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to install numpy on my PC but every time I try I get some sort of error. I tried using

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install numpy==1.9.2
```

and got this

```
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs



  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\lib

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python34\libs



  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_info:

  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python34\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python34\\lib
s']

  NOT AVAILABLE



lapack_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



running install

running build

running config_cc

unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler opti
ons

running config_fc

unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler opt
ions

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

creating build

creating build\src.win-amd64-3.4

creating build\src.win-amd64-3.4\numpy

creating build\src.win-amd64-3.4\numpy\distutils

building library "npymath" sources

No module named 'numpy.distutils.msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from d
istutils

Running from numpy source directory.

C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutils\system
_info.py:1603: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutils\system
_info.py:1612: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutils\system
_info.py:1615: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutils\system
_info.py:1505: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutils\system
_info.py:1516: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutils\system
_info.py:1519: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 1, in 

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\setup.py", lin
e 251, in 

    setup_package()

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\setup.py", lin
e 243, in setup_package

    setup(**metadata)

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutil
s\core.py", line 169, in setup

    return old_setup(**new_attr)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutil
s\command\install.py", line 62, in run

    r = self.setuptools_run()

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutil
s\command\install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run

    return distutils_install.run(self)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutil
s\command\build.py", line 39, in run

    old_build.run(self)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutil
s\command\build_src.py", line 153, in run

    self.build_sources()

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutil
s\command\build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources

    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutil
s\command\build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources

    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutil
s\command\build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources

    source = func(extension, build_dir)

  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 684, in get_mathlib_info

    st = config_cmd.try_link('int main(void) { return 0;}')

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_link

    self._check_compiler()

  File "C:\Users\JOOPED~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Root\numpy\numpy\distutil
s\command\config.py", line 57, in _check_compiler

    self.compiler.initialize()

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsal
l

    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: ['path']
```

(cmd won't show more info :p)

So I downloaded from source and got

```
Running from numpy source directory.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 260
    warnings.warn(msg)
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
```

I have no idea what's going on and what I should do, can anyone help me?
I'm running python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS-windows lacks the infrastructure that makes building software on UNIX-like systems like Linux and *BSD easy. So trying to build an extension like numpy is a painful experience for most.

If you ware stuck on ms-windows, the easiest way out is to use a Python distribution that comes with the extensions you need. For example [winpython](http://winpython.github.io/) or [anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install numpy
```

Has been broken for quite awhile. On Windows, you can download the numpy binary from SourceForge (sorry, I know SourceForge isn't a reputable download center anymore, but it's the only one with official NumPy binaries), [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/).

Comment: still not working :( I get the same warning and when I'm trying to run let's say, matplotlib for example, I get a error importing multiarray